# Why is my defined item not populating and storing from Scrapy?

Tags: python, html-parsing, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

Suppose I have the following site structure:

1. Start URLs: http://thomas.loc.gov/cgi-bin/query/z?c107:H.R.**%s**: where **%s** is an index 1-50 (a sample for illustration purposes).
2. "1st Layer": Bill text or link to multiple versions...
3. "2nd Layer": Bill Text w/ link to "Printer friendly" (plain text) versions.

The end goal of the script:

1. Navigate through start URLs; Parse URL, Title & Body; saving them to the starts.txt file
2. Extract "1st Layer" links from body of start URLs; navigate to these links; Parse URL, Title & Body; save them to the bills.txt file
3. Extract "2nd Layer" links from body of "1st Layer" URLs; navigate to these links; parse URL, Title & Body; save them to the versions.txt file

Suppose I have the following script:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class StartItem(Item):
    url = Field()
    title = Field()
    body = Field()

class BillItem(Item):
    url = Field()
    title = Field()
    body = Field()

class VersionItem(Item):
    url = Field()
    title = Field()
    body = Field()

class Lrn2CrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "lrn2crawl"
    allowed_domains = ["thomas.loc.gov"]
    start_urls = ["http://thomas.loc.gov/cgi-bin/query/z?c107:H.R.%s:" % bill for bill in xrange(000001,00050,00001) ### Sample of 40 bills; Total range of bills is 1-5767

    ]

    rules = (
            # Extract links matching /query/D fragment (restricting tho those inside the content body of the url); follow; & scrape all bill text.
            # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
            # Desired result: scrape all bill text & in the event that there are multiple versions, follow them & parse.
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/query/D'), restrict_xpaths=('//div[@id="content"]')), callback='parse_bills', follow=True),

            # Extract links in the body of a bill-version & follow them.
           #Desired result: scrape all version text & in the event that there are multiple sections, follow them & parse.
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/query/C'), restrict_xpaths=('//table/tr/td[2]/a/@href')), callback='parse_versions', follow=True)
        )

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        starts = hxs.select('//div[@id="content"]')
        scraped_starts = []
        for start in starts:
            scraped_start = StartItem() ### Start object defined previously
            scraped_start['url'] = response.url
            scraped_start['title'] = start.select('//h1/text()').extract()
            scraped_start['body'] = response.body
            scraped_starts.append(scraped_start)
            with open('starts.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write('url: {0}, title: {1}, body: {2}\n'.format(scraped_start['url'], scraped_start['title'], scraped_start['body']))
        return scraped_starts

    def parse_bills(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        bills = hxs.select('//div[@id="content"]')
        scraped_bills = []
        for bill in bills:
            scraped_bill = BillItem() ### Bill object defined previously
            scraped_bill['url'] = response.url
            scraped_bill['title'] = bill.select('//h1/text()').extract()
            scraped_bill['body'] = response.body
            scraped_bills.append(scraped_bill)
            with open('bills.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write('url: {0}, title: {1}, body: {2}\n'.format(scraped_bill['url'], scraped_bill['title'], scraped_bill['body']))
        return scraped_bills

    def parse_versions(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        versions = hxs.select('//div[@id="content"]')
        scraped_versions = []
        for version in versions:
            scraped_version = VersionItem() ### Version object defined previously
            scraped_version['url'] = response.url
            scraped_version['title'] = version.select('//h1/text()').extract()
            scraped_version['body'] = response.body
            scraped_versions.append(scraped_version)
            with open('versions.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write('url: {0}, title: {1}, body: {2}\n'.format(scraped_version['url'], scraped_version['title'], scraped_version['body']))
        return scraped_versions
```

This script appears to be doing everything that I want, except for navigating to the "2nd Layer" links and parsing the items (URL, Title & Body) of these sites. In other words, Scrapy is not crawling or parsing my "2nd Layer."

**To restate my question more simply: Why is Scrapy not populating my VersionItem and outputting it to my desired file: version.txt?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `restrict_xpaths` setting on the second `SgmlLinkExtractor`. Change it to:

```
restrict_xpaths=('//div[@id="content"]',)
```

Hope that helps.